# Error al utilizar Scrapy para extraer info de Stack Overflow: ERROR: Error download <GET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/>

Tags: python, scraping, scrapy, web-scrapping

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Scrapy, pero hasta ahora no he podido realizar ninguna operación puesto que al momento de correrlo en la terminal, me arroja el mismo error sin importar qué cambios realice.
Revisé si el XPath utilizado tenía defectos, pero no,

Aquí está mi código archivo.py:

```
from scrapy.item import Field 
from scrapy.item import Item 
from scrapy.spiders import Spider  
from scrapy.selector import Selector  
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader  
 
class Pregunta(Item):
    id = Field()
    pregunta = Field() 
 
class StackOverflowSpider(Spider):
    name = "mi_primer_spider"
    custom_settings = { 
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
    start_urls = ["https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector( response)  
        preguntas = sel.xpath('//div[@id="questions"]//div[@class="s-post-summary--content"]')
        # Para corrobrar que xpath está bien, ejecuten $x('//div[@id="questions"]//div[@class="s-post-summary--content"]') en la consola de cualquier navegador
        i = 1
        for pregunta in preguntas:
            item = ItemLoader(Pregunta(), pregunta)
            item.add_xpath('pregunta','.//h3/a/text()') 
            item.add_xpath('id', i)
            i += 1
            yield item.load_item() 

# scrapy runspider archivo.py -o apunte.csv
# TODO: Para hacer correr scrapy en terminal
```

Aquí están las librerías de mi entorno:

```
Package             Version
------------------- ---------
async-generator     1.10     
attrs               22.2.0   
Automat             22.10.0  
beautifulsoup4      4.12.1   
bs4                 0.0.1
certifi             2022.12.7
cffi                1.15.1
charset-normalizer  3.1.0
constantly          15.1.0
cryptography        40.0.1
cssselect           1.2.0
dnspython           2.3.0
exceptiongroup      1.1.1
filelock            3.10.7
h11                 0.14.0
hyperlink           21.0.0
idna                3.4
incremental         22.10.0
itemadapter         0.8.0
itemloaders         1.0.6
jmespath            1.0.1
lxml                4.9.2
outcome             1.2.0
packaging           23.0
parsel              1.7.0
Pillow              9.5.0
pip                 23.0.1
Protego             0.2.1
pyasn1              0.4.8
pyasn1-modules      0.2.8
pycparser           2.21
PyDispatcher        2.0.7
pymongo             4.3.3
pyOpenSSL           23.1.1
PySocks             1.7.1
queuelib            1.6.2
requests            2.28.2
requests-file       1.5.1
Scrapy              2.8.0
selenium            4.8.3
service-identity    21.1.0
setuptools          65.5.0
six                 1.16.0
sniffio             1.3.0
sortedcontainers    2.4.0
soupsieve           2.4
tldextract          3.4.0
trio                0.22.0
trio-websocket      0.10.2
Twisted             22.10.0
twisted-iocpsupport 1.0.3
typing_extensions   4.5.0
urllib3             1.26.15
w3lib               2.1.1
wsproto             1.2.0
zope.interface      6.0
```

Y este es el error que me sale:

```
2023-04-08 23:27:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.8.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2023-04-08 23:27:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 23.1.1 (OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023), cryptography 40.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP02023-04-08 23:27:01 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True,
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
               '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
2023-04-08 23:27:01 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\request.py:232: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get this warning if you have not defined a value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future version of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on how to handle this deprecation.
  return cls(crawler)

2023-04-08 23:27:01 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2023-04-08 23:27:01 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 8e984871b73479b1
2023-04-08 23:27:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-04-08 23:27:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-04-08 23:27:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-04-08 23:27:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-04-08 23:27:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-04-08 23:27:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-04-08 23:27:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-04-08 23:27:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1697, in _inlineCallbacks 
    result = context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 64, in process_response
    method(request=request, response=response, spider=spider)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\cookies.py", line 73, in process_response
    self._process_cookies(cookies, jar=jar, request=request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\cookies.py", line 44, in _process_cookies
    if cookie_domain and _is_public_domain(cookie_domain):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\cookies.py", line 19, in _is_public_domain
    parts = _split_domain(domain)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tldextract\tldextract.py", line 213, in __call__
    return self.extract_str(url, include_psl_private_domains)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tldextract\tldextract.py", line 228, in extract_str        
    return self._extract_netloc(lenient_netloc(url), include_psl_private_domains)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tldextract\tldextract.py", line 257, in _extract_netloc    
    suffix_index = self._get_tld_extractor().suffix_index(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tldextract\tldextract.py", line 298, in _get_tld_extractor 
    public_tlds, private_tlds = get_suffix_lists(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tldextract\suffix_list.py", line 67, in get_suffix_lists   
    return cache.run_and_cache(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tldextract\cache.py", line 206, in run_and_cache
    with FileLock(lock_path, timeout=self.lock_timeout):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\filelock\_api.py", line 227, in __enter__
    self.acquire()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\filelock\_api.py", line 191, in acquire
    raise Timeout(self._lock_file)
filelock._error.Timeout: The file lock 'C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock' could not be acquired.
2023-04-08 23:27:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-04-08 23:27:23 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 307,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 34471,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 20.529546,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 9, 4, 27, 23, 197048),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 9, 4, 27, 2, 667502)}
2023-04-08 23:27:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Cabe aclarar que estoy utilizando Windows 10 (también WSL con Ubuntu, pero dudo demasiado que ese detalle afecte al uso de Scrapy).
Al parecer por lo que visualizado en el código, creería que el problema sería la librería Twisted, ya que al momento de descargar Scrapy Twisted no necesariamente se descarga automáticamente en Windows en comparación con Linux o Mac.
Llevo varios días tratando de encontrar una posible solución, pero ninguna me ha permitido extraer los títutlos de la página principal de preguntas de Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ya me di cuenta de mi error, y fue bastante tonto realmente.
Para este caso en particular sucedió porque al momento de almacenar el dato del id, lo estaba guardando como un xpath en lugar de un value, por lo tanto generaba dichas incompatibilidades, no soy experto en el tema, pero supondría que esperaba una expresión XPath, y al ejecutarse y agotar el tiempo de espera, ocasionaba el problema, y de hecho se puede ver en el mensaje de error en la parte

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1697, in _inlineCallbacks 
    result = context.run(gen.send, result)
```

Para arreglarlo fue muy simple, cambié xpath por value:

```
item.add_value('id', i)
```